# RichFaces dataTable row deletion

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a column inside a `<rich:dataTable>` that contains `<a4j:commandButton>` for deleting rows.

Deleting rows works fine when calling bean's delete function (e.g. `#{bean.deleteCar(record.carId)}`) via commandButton's `action` attribute. Unfortunately, when using `<a4j:jsFunction>`'s `action` attribute the `record.carId` of the last row is passed to the bean, instead of the selected row.

Some code for clarification. The following deletes the car of the clicked row:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Delete"
                   action="#{bean.deleteCar(record.carId)}"/>
```

The following deletes last row's car:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Delete" 
                   onclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePane')}.show()">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="deleteCar" 
                    action="#{bean.deleteCar(record.carId)}"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePane')}.hide();"
                    render="carsTable"/>
</a4j:commandButton>

<rich:popupPanel id="confirmDeletePane" header="Delete" modal="true" autosized="true" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePane')}.hide();">
        <h:outputText value="Delete?"/>
        <h:panelGroup>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeletePane')}.hide(); return false;" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="OK" onclick="deleteCar(); return false;"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

As you can see I'm trying to confirm user's selection before deletion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a4j:jsFunction shouldn't be nested inside the commandButton. You should pass the value inside the modal and then on your confirmation button pass the value in the action attribute to the backing bean which is the id of the car.

Comment: @Ellie Thanks for the comment. I tried something similar: I passed the value directly to the backing bean with the use of <a4j:param>. If you have any sample code of passing a value to a modal (e.g. an index), feel free to share.

Comment: I'll try to create my own sample same as yours and then ill post the codes here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit&skin=blueSky) suggests, I concluded that a refined solution is to use indices for row selections. I'm copying here for future reference.

The commandLink (calls confirmPane):

```
<a4j:commandLink execute="@this"
                 render="@none"
                 oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.show()">
       <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/delete.gif" alt="delete" />
       <a4j:param value="#{it.index}" assignTo="#{carsBean.currentCarIndex}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

The confirmPane (calls the JS function):

```
<rich:popupPanel id="confirmPane" autosized="true">
        Delete?
        <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
        <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="remove(); return false;" />
</rich:popupPanel>
```

The jsFunction (calls Bean's function):

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="remove" action="#{carsBean.remove}" render="table" execute="@this"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('confirmPane')}.hide();" />
```

In the backing bean:

```
private int currentCarIndex; // with the getter/setter

public void remove() {
    // do your List removal (or DB transaction)
    // with the currentCarIndex
}
```